# Is Cloud Firestore data replicated over continents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was reading [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/01/cloud-firestore-in-general-availability.html). It make me wonder how data replication and fail overs handled in case of regional and multi-regional database projects. Article mentions that things are *over-simplified a bit*. But I hope there is certain truth to the point made in the article about data replication.

So my question is:

Lets say user is writing a social media app, where user in NY wants to look the profile of the user in Sydney.

- **Case 1:** If I am using regional databases for this app (only regional database in every region)
- **Case 2:** If I am using multi-regional databases for US and EU and regional database for others (Asia, Australia)

Is it possible for NY user to view the profile of the Sydney user in case 1, case 2? Is data replicated over continents in regional databases case?

Even if you use multi region databases which only available for US and EU for now. As I understood muti-region only replicated data within the regions of the same continent(NA, EU), not between continents. So how to build social media app to global market using Firestore?

Comment: While you cover a lot of valid topics, your question right now is too broad to answer in a reasonably concise way. I'd recommend limiting the scope so that it becomes answerable. A good indication of this is to have a single question with a single question mark, preferably at the end of the question. For example: "Is it possible for NY user to view the profile of the Sydney user if I use multiple regional databases?" is completely valid and clear. The answer is "yes" btw. "Cloud Firestore brings you ... automatic multi-region data replication": https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/

Comment: If I take away those small questions, it will make question incomplete. Think of those small question as prompt answer the overall question

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: Please supply your code @user158

Comment: @Programmer there is not any code, I want to know how things work? people over the world talk to same db, which cause high latency for some. Or whether the data is replicated over continents?

Comment: Ok sorry my mistake @user158

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Firestore data can be stored using a [multi-region location or a regional location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations). Using "multi-region locations" simply means storing data at multiple regions, located on the same continent. [EU and US are the two only choices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#location-mr). This means you cannot have data close to all users, globally.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Firestore database in a project, you get to choose whether to:

1. Store the data in a single regional location.

   In this case the data is stored in multiple data centers in a single geographical region. For example: `us-east4`, which are data centers in Northern Virginia.
2. Store the data in multi-region locations.

   In this case the data is stored in multiple data centers across multiple geographical regions. For example: `nam5/us-central`, which are data centers across the entire US.

For more on this, see the documentation on [location types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#types).

You will have to pick one of these options when you create the database. So you can't select a mix of of multi-region and single region locations.

All users of your app access the same data.  When data is written, it is automatically replicated across all data centers in the region(s).

Comment: So if we create a multi region database in US, thats mean user in Sydney have to work with database in US which results in higher latency? can you please tell

Comment: You are correct @user158: Using "multi-region locations" simply means multiple regions, located at the same continent, is used. EU and US seems to be the choices. This means you cannot have data close to all user globally. 

There is an article about Firestore latency and a web page to test latency from your location: https://dev.to/dbanisimov/firestore-dataflow-illustrated-and-measured-4kdg

Comment: Multi-regional simply means multiple regions within a large geographical area,  but not across continents. You can place the data in Australia, but then users in the US will get higher latency.

Comment: @RunarJordahl please take time to write an answer for this question, while quoting your resources.