# Cloud Firestore multi region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

is it possible to make asia-northeast1 and us-central1 and europe-north1 at same time??

I just want my firebase database responsing to be fast

thank you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389149/is-cloud-firestore-data-replicated-over-continents/55389697#55389697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#location-mr), at the time of this writing, your only options for multi region with Firestore are:

```
eur3    Europe          europe-west1, europe-west4
nam5    United States   us-central1, us-central2 (Oklahoma—private GCP region)
```