# what kind of bigtable replication do my datastore entities use?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

[datastore docs say](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore):

> the replication between Datastore servers. Replication is managed by
> Cloud Bigtable and Megastore, the underlying technologies for
> Datastore

[bigtable docs say](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/replication-overview):

> Replication for Cloud Bigtable enables you to increase the
> availability and durability of your data by copying it across **multiple
> regions** or **multiple zones** within the same region

How can I see in the datastore UI if I'm getting any replication? If I am getting replication how can I see if I'm getting cross region or cross zone replication for my datastore entities?

(The entities I'm looking at have been populated since 2017 if that's useful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question, is that if you are in a [multi-region](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations) then you can already access your data from multiple regions without worrying about asynchronous replication lag.

If you are really curious about Megastore replication, you can read the [Megastore paper](https://research.google/pubs/pub36971/).  However, what's more likely that you want is to read the trade-offs between [strong consistency & eventual consistency in Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore).

The locations for Cloud Datastore currently match those of Cloud Firestore in either mode.

Comment: I'm more concerned about redundancy as opposed to lag/consistency/access. I think this other answer rounds out what I'm looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/55389697/1168364.

Answer (score -1):

Cloud Datastore is only a regional service. You can't deploy it in multiple region in the same project.

Its brother (or sister, I don't know), Firestore, can be deployed in multi region.

So, Datastore is only mono region, but multi zonal in this unique region. And the BigTable replication mechanism is used to achieve this replication. You can't see this, it's serverless, transparent.

Comment: One reason why this answer was downvoted is because users can indeed use Datastore in a multi-region or regional location. As Jim mentioned, it is written in this doc: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations#types